# What does lockCanvas mean (elaborate)

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'v been coming to drawing graphics in Android. There's a lot of sample applications out there, but one thing I always seeing is lockCanvas. Can someone explain it closer since I really don't get it and also because im think it's important to understand to future programming?

An example:

```
try { 
    c = panel_thread.getHolder().lockCanvas(null);
    synchronized (panel_thread.getHolder()) {
        panel_thread.update();
        panel_thread.onDraw(c);
    }
}
```

This is what I have for now.
How should I interpret this correct? What does synchronized do? Why is it important to assign the canvas-object into a getHolder and lockCanvas?

This part is also confusing:

```
panel_thread.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

Why is this necessary? I really need a closer explanation. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`synchronized` indicates that only one thread can execute that block of code at a time.

In this example, without the `synchronized` block, multiple threads could draw graphics at the same time, and the results could be messy. Thus, `synchronized` ensures that only one thread can draw at a time.

`lockCanvas()` creates a surface area that you will write to. The reason it's called `lockCanvas()` is because until you call `unlockCanvasAndPost()` no other code can call `lockCanvas()` and write to the surface until your code is finished.

In general, locks are important to understand, specifically when it relates to multithreaded programming. A lock is a synchronization primitive that is used to guard against simultaneous accessing of resources/code by multiple threads. It gets it's name because it behaves much like a physical lock. Generally one thread can obtain a lock, and until it releases the lock, no other thread can obtain the lock. One potential gotcha to using a lock is that misuse of it can lead to a "dead lock" situation, where threads are left waiting for the lock, and it's never released.

Comment: Thanks, I assume that the getHolder just provide us with the area? And why does we send with null in the lockCanvas method?

Comment: Correct, it returns the Surface Holder object.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Just a little confusing that we're sending null into lockCanvas?

Comment: Right. you don't have to send null into `lockCanvas()`. lockCanvas has two signatures: one that is parameterless, and one that takes a reference to a dirty rectangle. Since you're passing in a "null" dirty rectangle, you might as well be calling the parameterless `lockCanvas()`

Comment: @Alan, re: passing null, the documentation for `lockCanvas(Rect)` says it does not require all pixels to be drawn outside the dirty rectangle; I see two possible interpretations: the one you stated, and the other is it does not require any pixel to be drawn.  The problem is, almost every example I've seen uses this convention without a comment, and the documentation doesn't say what will happen if the Rect is null.

Comment: This means the lockCanvas and unlockCanvasAndPost can be run on any thread, right? And better not to do it on the UI thread, right?