# How to draw on Canvas in another thread?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing the application, and I need that drawingg is executed in another thread. Now my code is:

```
public class PainterView extends View implements DrawingListener {

    //private GestureDetector detector;
    private Context context;
    private Painter painter;
    private Bitmap background;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Paint bitmapPaint;
    private Path path;
    private Paint paint;

    private float x;
    private float y;

    private boolean isErasing=false;
    private boolean isTextDrawing=false;

    private ExecutorService pool;

    public PainterView(Context context, Painter painter) {

        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.painter = painter;
        pool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        //detector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            pool.submit(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    synchronized (PainterView.this) {
                        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                    }
                }

            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                painter.touchStart(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                painter.touchMove(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                painter.touchUp();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureUpdate(Bitmap background, Bitmap bitmap, Paint bitmapPaint, Path path, Paint paint) {
        this.background=background;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.bitmapPaint = bitmapPaint;
        this.path = path;
        this.paint = paint;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setPainter(Painter painter) {
        this.painter = painter;
    }
}
```

I thought that if I uses ExecutorService then the application can draw in another thread, but it doesn't work - when I draw the screen of device blinkes. So, please, tell me, how can I use multithreading for drawing using SurfaceHolder and other elements? I need to make as few as possible changes in my code.

Comment: Is this for Android?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (it would show imports).

Comment: What happens if you just remove the `pool.submit(new Runnable` so that the drawing happens directly in the `onDraw`?

Comment: No, I need to draw in another thread. But if I don't use submit then it won't work in another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only draw in the main UI thread. You should use SurfaceView, since it was made specifically to support drawing from secondary threads.

> One of the purposes of this class is to provide a surface in which a
>   secondary thread can render into the screen. If you are going to use
>   it this way, you need to be aware of some threading semantics.

[source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)

See also this video: [Learn Android Tutorial 1.28- Introduction to the SurfaceView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2YogvILjvo)

Comment: So, If I use SurfaceView it will be executed in another thread or which benefites I will get?

Comment: If you use surface view, you can grab a canvas from it and draw on it from a secondary thread (your executorservice). Watch a video, there are some examples

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to try it.

Comment: It's worth noting that SurfaceView was designed with the intent that only a single instance would ever be visible to the user.  For some projects that might be a deal breaker.

Comment: Almost forgot to cite my source:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/fQihJKLki7M