# back press on a null pointer reference when implemented AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-canvas

I created a file called `JoyStickView` which extends `SurfaceView`.
In my `JoyStickView.java` file, I have the following function which calls the `AsyncTask` to draw two joysticks:

```
private void drawJoystick(float hatX, float hatY) {
    // Only draw the joystick when SurfaceView has been created
    if (getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) {
        new MultiplyTask().execute();
    }
}
```

And the inner class `AsyncTask` is shown below:

```
 public class MultiplyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Bitmap, Bitmap[]> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(Void... progress_data) {

            Bitmap[] bitmapArray = new Bitmap[2];
            bitmapArray[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.joystick_base);
            bitmapArray[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.joystick_hat);
            //publishProgress(bitmapArray);
            return bitmapArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... bitmapArray) {
            //super.onProgressUpdate(values);\
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] bitmapArray) {
            // super.onPostExecute(s);
            myCanvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
            myCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            switch (getId()) {
                case R.id.joystickRight:
                    // draw_joystick_base(myCanvas, R.drawable.joystick_base);

                    float c = bitmapArray[0].getWidth() / 2;
                    float d = bitmapArray[0].getHeight() / 2;
                    myCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray[0], centerX - c, centerY - d, new Paint());
                    break;
                case R.id.joystickLeft:
                    // draw_joystick_base(myCanvas, R.drawable.joystick_base);

                    float c1 = bitmapArray[0].getWidth() / 2;
                    float d1 = bitmapArray[0].getHeight() / 2;
                    myCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray[0], centerX - c1, centerY - d1, new Paint());
                    break;

            }

            float a = bitmapArray[1].getWidth() / 2;
            float b = bitmapArray[1].getHeight() / 2;
            myCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray[1], hatX_tmp - a, hatY_tmp - b, new Paint());
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(myCanvas);
            // Do things like update the progress bar
        }

        void stopTask() {
            MultiplyTask a = new MultiplyTask();
            a.cancel(true);
        }
    }
```

Everything works great until I hit the back button, and the app just crashes and gave me the following null pointer error.

```
  06-03 15:06:15.505 4478-4478/com.example.android.toybot E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.android.toybot, PID: 4478
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawColor(int, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.android.toybot.JoyStickView$MultiplyTask.onPostExecute(JoyStickView.java:304)
            at com.example.android.toybot.JoyStickView$MultiplyTask.onPostExecute(JoyStickView.java:274)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:661)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:678)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5688)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

`JoyStickView.java:304` is this line: `myCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);` I thought of cancelling my `AsyncTask` during `onstop()` but this does not seem to work. Anyone have any advice on what I can do?

**Update:**
Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489571/run-surfaceview-off-ui-thread), I was able to follow the [LunarLander](https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/blob/master/LunarLander/src/com/example/android/lunarlander/LunarView.java) example and implement a `new Runnable()` to achieve what I needed.

Comment: What does `getHolder().lockCanvas()` do? Can you show it? Your problem is there

Comment: it provides an area so that I can draw on it. I didn't implement the function, it came from SurfaceView. I found this link to be helpful for me to understand it better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322144/what-does-lockcanvas-mean-elaborate @cricket_007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing a UI element from a separate thread which is not recommended. The `NullPointerException` is pretty straightforward. `myCanvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();` is setting a null reference to the `myCanvas` attribute when you are finishing the activity using the back button press.

If the code was inside your UI thread (i.e. inside any function which is in your activity life-cycle), this could have handled by the activity life-cycle functions like `onStop` or `onDestroy`. However, you are trying to change a UI element (`myCanvas` in your case) from a separate thread other than UI thread which is out of the `Activity` resource management scope. Hence the `getHolder().lockCanvas()` is getting a null reference for the canvas and you are getting the `NullPointerException` on drawing.

This can be easily avoided by implementing an interface as a listener to your `AsyncTask`, so that the listener function resides in your `Activity` and handles the resources properly. For example, you might consider creating an `interface` like this.

```
public interface MultiplyResponseReceiver {
    void onMultiplyResponseReceived(Bitmap[] bitmapArray);
}
```

Now take an attribute of this interface in your `AsyncTask` like this.

```
public class MultiplyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Bitmap, Bitmap[]> {

    public MultiplyResponseReceiver listener;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(Void... progress_data) {

        Bitmap[] bitmapArray = new Bitmap[2];
        bitmapArray[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.joystick_base);
        bitmapArray[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.joystick_hat);
        //publishProgress(bitmapArray);
        return bitmapArray;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... bitmapArray) {
        //super.onProgressUpdate(values);\


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] bitmapArray) {
        // super.onPostExecute(s);
        listener.onMultiplyResponseReceived(bitmapArray);
    }
}
```

Now implement the interface in your `Activity` like this.

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MultiplyResponseReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onMultiplyResponseReceived() {

        myCanvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        myCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        switch (getId()) {
            case R.id.joystickRight:
                // draw_joystick_base(myCanvas, R.drawable.joystick_base);

                float c = bitmapArray[0].getWidth() / 2;
                float d = bitmapArray[0].getHeight() / 2;
                myCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray[0], centerX - c, centerY - d, new Paint());
                break;
            case R.id.joystickLeft:
                // draw_joystick_base(myCanvas, R.drawable.joystick_base);

                float c1 = bitmapArray[0].getWidth() / 2;
                float d1 = bitmapArray[0].getHeight() / 2;
                myCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray[0], centerX - c1, centerY - d1, new Paint());
                break;
        }

        float a = bitmapArray[1].getWidth() / 2;
        float b = bitmapArray[1].getHeight() / 2;
        myCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray[1], hatX_tmp - a, hatY_tmp - b, new Paint());
        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(myCanvas);
        // Do things like update the progress bar
    }
}
```

And while launching the `AsyncTask` in your activity, do not forget to assign the listener to it.

```
MultiplyTask task = new MultiplyTask();
task.listener = this; 
task.execute();
```

The code is not tested and might contain errors. Please modify as per your necessity. I think you have got the idea already.

Comment: thank you for your help, your explanation make things a lot more clearer. I am trying to  implement onMultiplyResponseReceived() in my JoyStickActivity.java, I am unable to use getHolder in JoystickActivity.java. I tried to pass the variable down from JoyStickView.java, but it gave me a null pointer. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think `getHolder` method should be called like `surfaceView.getHolder()`

Comment: thank you, would I still keep my drawJoystick() function in my JoyStickView.java?

Comment: Sorry, I am still debugging the code, it seems to still have null pointer error. Can you tell me the difference between  `new MultiplyTask().execute();` in my `drawJoystick() ` and the `task.execute();`? Thank you.

Comment: I wasn't able to implement an interface in the asynctask, but I was able to use a runnable thread to do the same thing that I wanted to do. but your answer definitely help me understand the problem I was having.

Comment: Great to know you have solved the problem and I could help you. My pleasure. :)